# About the jsp life cycle

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, lifecycle

When a request is mapped to a JSP page, the web container first checks whether the JSP page’s servlet is older than the JSP page.

What does it mean by the JSP page’s servlet is older than the JSP page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means if your JSP page last modified time is later than the JSP compiled servlet. If yes then it will generate the servlet again and compile.

Comment: each and every time request  goes to  servlet engine  check for modification   if modification has been done then it modify according request and process it send back  response  to user

Comment: That is why JSP should be precompiled and bundled with the war for performance reasons.